# Log in using SSH as different user - perform script and go to next one

Tags: shell-script

i try to run some script located on servers specified in list but i have a problem with log in as specified user. To clarify it I log in to server1 as user0 then run this script and I except the script will be switch my user0 to user1 and as user1 perform action from lines below for servers specified in list:

```
[user0@server1 home]$ /home/user0/my_script.sh

#!/bin/bash
sudo su - user1
#SERV=(serv1 serv2 serv3)

for HOST in ${SERV[@]}; do
   ssh -t user1@${SERV} 'cd /opt/directory1/directory2/var; sudo /opt/custom/scripts/script.sh'

    if [[ $?=0 ]]; then
        echo "Commnad on $SERV executed!"
     else
        echo "$SERV do not exist!"
    fi
done
```

The proble is with switch user from user which run script to user which will be perform ssh ( user1 have included rsa keys ) but script always ask me about password for user1

Answer (score 0):

If you want user0 to be able to do ssh user1@${SERV} without being prompted for password, then you need user1 to trust user0.  In other words, user0's public key needs to be added to user1's authorized_keys file.  You can do this by running

```
ssh-copy-id user1@${SERV}
```

for each server in that you want user0 to have access as user1.